# cmake -D <var>:<type>=<value> what does the parameter "-D" mean

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake to install opencv. In the opencv instruction page, I find the following example:

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

As I understand it, I should use cmake to generate Makefile in the new directory I created, which in this example should be ~/opencv/release.
But I don't quite understand the last line. In cmake help, I find:

```
cmake -D <var>:<type>=<value> = create a cmake cache entry
```

What does it mean? Especially this part: `"<var>:<type>=<value>"`, I don't understand why the example gives `"CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE"` and`"CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .."`

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems that the `:<type>` is optional, although it doesn't say so explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the CMake Documentation:

> - -D <var>:<type>=<value>: Create a cmake cache entry.
>     When cmake is first run in an empty build tree, it creates a CMakeCache.txt file and populates it with customizable settings for the project. This option may be used to specify a setting that takes priority over the project's default value. The option may be repeated for as many cache entries as desired.

The `:<type>` could be read as optional.

Comment: The types available are better described in the documentation for [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/set.html)

Comment: I searched for CMake Documentation and could not find that entry. Thanks for putting it here!. Could you provide a link? I am now looking for the "-B" and the "-H" option

Comment: @KansaiRobot: you can find the documentation following this link https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try:

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE' -D'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local'
```

Just use '   ' surround the parameters and do not leave any blank between -D and ' and it can work.

I encountered some problems when I configure OpenCV with -D parameter.

And I think -D option just change some default parameters for compiling and installing the pkg.

Just as you inferred, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE` means you want to build a "Release" version of the opencv package, and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local` means you want to specify the install path of it while using `make install` command.

Answer (score 0):

You might wonder why it's called `-D`. The `D` stands for **define/definition**. Using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE` defines `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` with value `RELEASE` in the CMake cache.

From the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options):

> Create or update a CMake CACHE entry.

- The main use of this to configure your build without changing the `CMakeLists.txt` file, for example, to switch between debug and release builds without editing files.
- The reason it's not a variable, but a **cache** entry is for your convenience. Rerunning the command uses your previously set value.